# integer from mongo takes float with E+ number, why?

Tags: php, mongodb

All of my friends use one database.
When their take data from database, they have got int.
I have got numbers like 12334345345E+17
This data takes from numberLong type, for example NumberLong("995713968209604608");
I have got 64bit system, where is the problem And how I can solve it? I can't continue work;

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `mongo shell` treats all numbers as floating-point values. The mongo shell provides the `NumberLong()` class to handle `64-bit` integers. see this link : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/